# Anime of 80-90's name. Robot fight

Tags: story-identification, anime

Would appreciate if someone helps me with the name of the old anime I watched as a kid. The anime was released at about 80-90’s. I don’t remember the script, but one scene is stuck in my memory. The main character, blond big guy (probably he was a cyborg) with sunglasses, is fighting a robot on some construction site. The robot is not a cyborg, I mean, you can see, that it is made of metal and it is a killing machine.

Blond guy was losing until he understood, that the robot is sensitive to sound. So, the blond guy took a metal ball and hit some construction. The killer robot was confused and the blond guy destroyed it. After that, in the end, the blond guy is smoking cigarettes and you see the titles. Does anybody have any ideas, what is the name of this anime? Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You're thinking of seminal anime [Cyber City Oedo 808](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyber_City_Oedo_808), Episode 2.

Gogol is a cyborg with a visor (not blonde, he has a mohawk).

[image]

He fights against an experimental cyborg (which does look like a robot, but turns out to have a human head) on a large metal tower. The cyborg has psychic powers and is winning, but Gogol discovers it is sensitive to sound. He defeats it by smashing a metal bar onto the building.
At the end Gogol collapses on the tower and it's actually his 'boss' Hasegawa who smokes a cigarette.

The scene you are thinking of (in fact the entire episode) is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vCSTGjmRHps#t=37m50s).

Comment: This answer could use some fleshing out. What about this episode matches up?

Comment: Edited to provide more details.